# Bootstrap inline form example does not work on jsFiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I copied the example for inline form element to jsFiddle, I also added the Bootstrap js and css as external resources, but the example does not show inline.

How come? See http://jsfiddle.net/VTufV/

Since stackoverflow needs some code, here is the code I copied from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny yours is actually working. just resize the output pane and see yourself! [image]